# Bulk load XML files into Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm looking into using Cassandra to store 50M+ documents that I currently have in XML format. I've been hunting around but I can't seem to find anything I can really follow on how to bulk load this data into Cassandra without needing to write some Java (not high on my list of language skills!).

I can happily write a script to convert this data into any format if it would make the loading easier although CSV might be tricky given the body of the document could contain just about anything!

Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks

Si

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to convert the XML to a delimited format of some kind (i.e. CSV), then here are a couple options:

1. The [`COPY` command](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) in `cqlsh`. This actually got a big [performance boost](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-we-optimized-cassandra-cqlsh-copy-from) in a recent version of Cassandra.
2. The [`cassandra-loader` utility](https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader). This is a lot more flexible and has a bunch of different options you can tweak depending on the file format.

If you're willing to write code other than Java (for example, Python), there are [Cassandra drivers available](https://academy.datastax.com/downloads/download-drivers?dxt=DX) for a bunch of programming languages. No need to learn Java if you've got another language you're better with.

Comment: Thanks I think cassandra-loader will do the job, my concern with CSV was the random nature of the content in the body of the XML but it says I can use a custom delimiter so that should work a treat, failing that I can go for a python approach, I would go C# but that would mean getting 50M+ files from the linux server to a windows server so python approach sounds more appealing if the loader has issues. Cheers